# Django and DRF: serializer for a user model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am wrote a serializer for the User model in Django with DRF:

the model:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    # all models should be inheritted from this model
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class User(AbstractBaseUser, BaseModel):
    username = models.CharField(
        ugettext('Username'), max_length=255,
        db_index=True, unique=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        ugettext('Email'), max_length=255, db_index=True,
        blank=True, null=True, unique=True
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('email', 'password',)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'
```

the serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, user, validated_data):
        user = super().update(user, validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

It works. But I probably do two calls instead of one on every create/update and the code looks a little bit weird(not DRY).
Is there an idiomatic way to do that?

```
$python -V
Python 3.7.3

Django==2.2.3
djangorestframework==3.10.1
```

Comment: *"I probably do two calls instead of one on every create/update "* two calls? how? I don't get it

Comment: `user = super().create(validated_data)` <- first
`user.save()` <-- second

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own user manager by overriding `BaseUserManager` and use `set_password()` method there. There is a full example in django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). So your `models.py` will be:

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    # all models should be inheritted from this model
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class User(AbstractBaseUser, BaseModel):
    username = models.CharField(
        ugettext('Username'), max_length=255,
        db_index=True, unique=True
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        ugettext('Email'), max_length=255, db_index=True,
        blank=True, null=True, unique=True
    )

    # don't forget to set your custom manager
    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('email', 'password',)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'users'
```

Then, you can directly call `create_user()` in your serializer's `create()` method. You can also add a custom update method in your custom manager.

```py
# serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = models.User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            password=validated_data['password']
        )
        return user
```

Comment: I need to call `set_password` and `save` of the model. 

or I need to call `create_user`, but then I can't call super on `create` in serializer

Comment: https://github.com/kharandziuk/django-jwt-authentication - here you can find the code with some tests. Try what you are proposing. And try to run the tests

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve the issue,

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return models.User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, user, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        if password is not None:
            user.set_password(password)
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(user, field, value)
        user.save()
        return user
```

The **`create_user()`** method uses the **`set_password()`** method to set the hashable password.

Comment: yep, it should work. The only problem: we don't call super of the serializer in this case. and it contains some code. what is your opinion, Is it a problem? it  has some code related to the validation

Comment: It won't be a problem unless you are trying to save some ***relational data*** (`FK` or `M2M` fields)